# Can an App pull data from Server using Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to sync data between my App and AppEngine server using GCM. The data, for example, is a set of user profiles, consisting of name, age, gender, a profile image (in BLOB) etc.

I know that my App can execute a POST request (is this the best way to do it?) to send data to the server. And the server can send a message via GCM to my App, asking to delete and/or update a specific user entry. But is there a way my App can pull data from the Server, rather than waiting for the server to send message?

The reason I want to do this is that, when executing POST request, I only want to update newly added data on my App to the server. So I need to pull all existing IDs from the server first, then do an incremental updating. Otherwise, every time I will need to update all my date to the server, which is time-consuming.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a GET request?

Comment: Thanks Peter! Do you have any example snippets on how to use GET via GCM and process the Http response on an Android App? I searched online, but no luck...Also do you think using GET&POST is the best way to do the communications? Do we need to use something like requestFactory? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your POST request will return an HTTP response to your app.  You can put your data in the response.

Comment: Thanks. But by issuing a POST, I've already uploaded all my data to my server?